# why CGAL::Triangulation_3::locate does not give you the vertices of the tetrahedron contains your request point?

Tags: cgal, triangulation, delaunay, locate

I am using `CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_3` to generate mesh for interpolation. I have three questions regarding `Triangulation_3::locate`.

- In the following, if `Cell` returns the four vertices of the tetrahedron which contains the point `Location`? http://doc.cgal.org/latest/TDS_3/classTriangulationDataStructure__3_1_1Cell.html

  ```
  Delaunay_triangulation_3 Mesh(Points.begin(), Points.end());
  Cell_handle Cell =  Mesh.locate(Location);
  ```
- What would `Cell` give back when `Location` sits on one of tetrahedron vertices, edges, facets? Does `Cell` only return the vertex where `Location` is, the two vertices of the edge, the three vertices of the facet? What will fill `Cell->vertex(vertex_no)`, while the `vertex_no` shall be 0,1,2,3?
- Under which circumstance could it be possible that the tetrahedron built by the four vertices given by `Cell->vertex(vertex_no)` does not contain point `Location`? Why I have a lot of this case? Also `Cell->vertex(vertex_no)` seems give the same combination of the four vertices with high repetition while `Location` is not surrounded by them?
  http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_3/classCGAL_1_1Triangulation__3.html#a63e8c40604ae19d745b5f83e0e927379

Comment: Your last link already seems to answer most of your questions...

Comment: @MarcGlisse Yes...just not very sure... so 1st is yes.. 2nd as if `Location` is on the boundary, it gives any one of this tetrahedron holding the point (the query)?..But My major confusion is why would the `Location` (or `query` in the link) can lie outside of the tetrahedron which given by the `Cell`

Comment: What makes you think that can happen? If you have a (small) testcase, maybe you should have started with it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there are several overloads of the function `locate()`.  You should take the one with `Locate_type lt`, `int li`, and `lj`. This will tell you if the query is in the cell, on a face, on an edge, or on a vertex, and `li` and `lj` will tell you on which face,edge,or vertex.